# iPad hijacking at night

Tags: united-kingdom, computer-misuse-act

We are having issues with our neighbors. I play music from my iPad at night to help me sleep, using headphones, and my neighbor has been hijacking it and playing discordant sounds to wake me up in the night is this illegal?

Comment: You might also want to ask about this at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Easy solution: sleep in a [metal box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Unless you're streaming your music, in which case that wouldn't work.

Comment: Change your passwords to your devices, and network equipment.

Comment: Well damn. That's a douchy thing to do.

Comment: If i told u all the other anti social behaviour thye have been doing u wouldnt believe it!

Comment: Don't use a legal solution when a technical solution will work.  Fix your network security, and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be unauthorized access to a computer. The offence is found in [Section 1 of the Computer Misuse Act 1990](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1).

Note that this is a criminal offence, approaching the police about it might be the best way of handling the situation (if you want to go that route, and also, I'm not a lawyer).